# How to find the greatest value of elements in this kind of Array?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for correct code so function named "finder()" can execute and find the highest value in Array named "sum" . 
When press "Find max" button result is :"[object HTMLInputElement] "
Thank you for any help!
Here is code:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Max</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var sum = document.getElementsByName('addends');
      function add() {
          var x = document.getElementById('apendiks');
          x.innerHTML+="<br/><input type='text' name='addends' size='7'>";
        }

       function finder() {  
          var max = sum[0];           
           for(i=0; i<sum.length;i++){

                if(sum[i] > max){
                   max = sum[i];
                }                 
           } 

          document.getElementById('showMaxValue').innerHTML = max;
        }

        function gather() {

          var total=0;
          for(i=0; i < sum.length; i++){

              total+=parseFloat(sum[i].value);
          }
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = total;
        }
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add a new box"> </p>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="" value="-"> </p>

  <div id="apendiks"></div>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="gather()" value="Total sum"> </p>
    <p>Score: <b id="score"></b></p>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="finder()" value="Find max"> </p>
   <p id="showMaxValue"></p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: what if I entered `398 49 fdr` into the text field `'addends'` ?

Comment: Sum[] is an array of html input objects. I think you are trying to get the value out of the input, but instead you are comparing input elements to each other instead of the value they contain.

Comment: Multiple problems ... please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: @charlietfl but he got the result `When press "Find max" button result is :"[object HTMLInputElement] "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> var sum = document.getElementsByName('addends');

This line will give you a list of Nodes, not an Array.

In your `finder` method, you need to treat it as such

```
  function finder() 
  {
       var max = paeseInt(sum[0].value) ;
       for(i=0; i<sum.length;i++){
            if(parseInt(sum[i].value) > max && !isNaN(sum[i].value)){ //assuming that strings should be ignored
               max = parseInt(sum[i].value) ;
            }
       } 
       document.getElementById('showMaxValue').innerHTML = max;
  }
```

Comment: what if I entered `398-49fdr` into the text field `addends` ?

Comment: what should be the output in this case?

Comment: what output will give your solution with this input value `-f0j381` ? How do you think ...

Comment: Same here...comparing strings not numbers

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest But what is the intended output? Do you want to ignore the strings?

Comment: he said: "find the highest value". You should elaborate what exactly he(author) is expecting to get under that "highest value" with untidy input

Comment: `sum[i].value` is string regardless if user input is a number or not

Comment: Thank you gurvinder372 for correct answer! Thank you all who post answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.value` to get the value of input field

```html
<html>
  <head>
   <title>Max</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var sum = document.getElementsByName('addends');
        function add() {

          var x = document.getElementById('apendiks');

          x.innerHTML+="<br/><input type='text' name='addends' size='7'>";

        }

        function finder() {

          var max = sum[0].value;

           for(i=0; i<sum.length;i++){



                if(sum[i].value > max){


                   max = sum[i].value;

                }

           } 

          document.getElementById('showMaxValue').innerHTML = max;
        }





        function gather() {



          var total=0;
          for(i=0; i < sum.length; i++){

              total+=parseFloat(sum[i].value);
          }
          document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = total;
        }

        </script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="add()" value="Add a new box"> </p>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="" value="-"> </p>


  <div id="apendiks"></div>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="gather()" value="Total sum"> </p>
    <p>Score: <b id="score"></b></p>
   <p><input type="button" onclick="finder()" value="Find max"> </p>
   <p id="showMaxValue"></p>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Still comparing strings